# Selectively searching from a set of tables in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I wanted to know if it's possible to have one query which I could design so that it would take a certain record from only one table i.e. I have 3 tables and my query, based on a certain parameter would choose one table to take the records from.

Comment: Source table cannot be dynamic. There is no way to build a query object to do this. Why would you have 3 tables of same structure anyway?

Comment: The tables wouldn't have the same structure. What I have is a set of products which are part of different product lines and each product lines which have parameters unique to only them. So I wanted to pull the parameters from one specific table based on an input I gave.

Comment: Then probably have to build different forms and reports and use code to select appropriate object to open.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so. I just wanted to know if there was a more efficient way to do it. Thanks for help.

Comment: @June7 You can work around that limitation by using a union query that contains all tables. That way this certainly is possible.

Comment: Okay, there is a way to search all records from 3 tables by using UNION query. OP says the 3 tables have different structure so building the UNION will have to account for that. UNION query is not updatable, which is fine for a report but I assumed OP wanted to use a form.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this if all tables have equal field names using a UNION query, and by adding a field that specifies from which table the row originated:

```
PARAMETERS ParamTableName VARCHAR(255);
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT *, "Table1" As TableName FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT *, "Table2" As TableName FROM Table2
UNION ALL
SELECT *, "Table3" As TableName FROM Table3
) TheTables
WHERE TableName = ParamTableName
```